# Skyrim keeps freezing when it is loading an area?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

Whenever I fast travel, go into a cave or enter other areas, the loading takes a long time.

I am playing the game on PS3, so I try to quit the game by using the PS button to get to the menu but it does not load. I also tried turning off the console but then everything freezes.

What should I do?

Comment: How long is the loading time if you succeed to load an area? Or won't it ever load?

Comment: How old is your PS3?

Comment: This happens on console, not  just PS3.  I've played this on XBOX 360, PS3, and PC.  It has frozen on me on both consoles but not PC.  I'm pretty sure it happens when you've been playing for a while and the console gets hot.  Try moving your console somewhere with better ventilation.

Answer (score 2):

Long load times **CAN** be a result of a save file getting too big in size.
As you might have noticed while playing, the size of the save file increases **slightly** as you progress through the game which results in longer loading times and in the worst case scenario, the game crashing. This is a problem, which as far as I know, exclusive to the PS3 version of the game.

Here are a few things you can do to keep the file size in check:

1) Close doors behind you so that the game does not have to save them in the "open" state.

2) Do not drop your loot on the ground because the game has to remember where you dropped it, if you are encumbered, dump it in a corpse instead as they disappear in a couple of days and so will the loot. Basically avoid interaction with things that you do not intend on using. For example: jumping on a table and dropping the plates and food on it, the game will have to save that, don't do it! Try your best not to alter things from when you started the game and you should have a much lower file size.

3) Do not take every quest you come along and fill your quest log with tons of quests, finish the older ones and then pick the new ones.

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to agree with Lovejinder_LJ. His solution can help out lowering the loading times in game. My recommendation though is to "clean out" your Ps3.
Start by finding your old games, apps, and other things that you don't use and delete them. They use up a lot of memory on your console and can affect the performance.
The second thing you should do is unplug your Playstation. It is recommended that you have a can of compressed air and you blow out your console, and if the warranty happens to be voided/expired, then take the extra step of taking off the plastic covering to blow it out. You don't need to do anything major on the inside, just blow it out with your can of air. Also remember to clean all the dust out from where you keep your system.
Finally hook it back up with all the wires and everything except for the power cord. Hold down the eject button and then plug in the power cord while still holding the eject button. After a few seconds of holding the button down, the fans will go into overdrive and will remove all the extra dust and other things inside your system. You will have to unplug the power and then plug it back in after it is done. (You will know when it has started and when it has finished by the noise of the fans.)
*note: If you have never used a can of compressed air before, make sure you do not hold it up-side-down. Doing so will cause the air inside to spray out freezing cold and can damage your system if you blow it out improperly.*